# how to add the button onto the furnace GUI in minecraft

Tags: java, jar, minecraft, openai-api

I want to create a 1.19 forge Minecraft Mod that shows a button with custom text that server-side dupes when the Furnace GUI is open, but the problem is that i can't get it to work! I also tried asking ChatGPT and Copilot, but still doesn't work. I haven't found tutorials on youtube, so can please someone post a code and clear instructions on how to use the code? (i'm using fabric for mc 1.19,java 17.0.1 and Intellij Idea as java IDE)

i tried asking AI's but didnt work, so can please someone hlep me create this mod that server-side dupes? i know no one's gonna answer because its too complicated, but atleast help me do that in single player

Comment: Your question looks to be very broad, too broad for you to solve, for AI to solve, and likely for us to solve. Best to break the problem down into its constituent smaller parts and then try to solve each small step, one at a time, in isolation if need be. Do this, and if still stuck, you'll likely get better help, both here and with AI.